# why the pandas operation df.loc[:, ['a', 'b'] = df.loc[:, ['c', 'd'] does not change the values in df.loc[:, ['a', 'b']?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to use `df.loc[:, ['a', 'b'] = df.loc[:, ['c', 'd'].values` to successfully change the values in `df.loc[:, ['a', 'b']` why?

In the contrast, `df.loc[:, ['a'] = df['c']` works! why?

`df` is a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: add sample data in your question

Answer (score 1):

Answer is for oldier pandas versions, in last version of pandas all working nice, it means not necessary convert to numpy arrays or rename columns.

Reason is called index alignement, here is assigned different columns names `c,d` to `a,b` columns, so failed. For prevent it is used converting selected DataFrame to numpy array, because array has no columns, so working nice.

Or you can use `rename` for same columns names in both DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a':list('abcdef'),
         'b':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'c':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'd':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
})

df.loc[:, ['a', 'b']] = df.loc[:, ['c', 'd']].rename(columns={'c':'a', 'd':'b'})
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
0  7  1  7  1
1  8  3  8  3
2  9  5  9  5
3  4  7  4  7
4  2  1  2  1
5  3  0  3  0
```

In Series are not columns, so working nice.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from what @jezrael answer, you can reassign column using the same syntax for a new column definition, what I mean is:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':list('abcdef'),
         'b':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'c':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'd':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

df[['a', 'b']] = df.loc[:, ['c', 'd']]
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['c', 'd']]
```

Both lines will yield the expected result. On the other hand, to use loc on the left hand side you can convert the right hand side to numpy array or rename column as in jezrael answer:

```
df.loc[:, ['a', 'b']] = df.loc[:, ['c', 'd']].to_numpy()
```